# How can compare Date on mongo without time?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is a sample data

```
[{ date: '2020-05-21T14:02:00.0123 }, { date: '2020-05-22T14:02:00.0123 }, { date: '2020-05-23T14:02:00.0123 }]
```

I want to filter records of 22-May or earlier, here is my expected:

```
[{ date: '2020-05-21T14:02:00.0123 }, { date: '2020-05-22T14:02:00.0123 }]
```

I tried with this query:

```
{ date: { $lte: new Date('2020-05-22') }}
```

But it returns only data earlier 22-May. I think problem is `{ date: { $lte: new Date('2020-05-22') }}` will data.date lte 2020-05-22T00:00:00.000

How I can exclude time ?

Comment: Your sample data has `date` field vaule as a **string data type**. You are trying to compare with `date` data type:  `{ date: { $lte: new Date('2020-05-22') } }`

Comment: Convert your data into proper `Date` objects, then your comparison  will work. **Never** store Date values as strings.

Comment: I converted to `Date` type but it still not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to match type of input with type of `date` field in document, either both should be `Date`'s or `strings`. I would highly suggest maintain dates as dates in DB. Also you need to know that dates in MongoDB are of format `ISODate()` and holds `UTC` date.

1. If your DB `date` field is of type `date` :

> I want to filter records of 22-May or earlier

As you wanted to get documents **<= 22-May**, then sending `new Date('2020-05-22')` doesn't work. Cause :

when you do `new Date('2020-05-22')`, it will give you `Fri May 22 2020 00:00:00 GMT` only if you belong to `UTC`, for example if you're in New York America which is 4 hours behind UTC then it would result in `Thu May 21 2020 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` which represents EDT, basically it's your system/app server time i.e; local date time.

So if your region is behind `UTC` then you'll get a back date `Thu May 21 2020` otherwise if it's ahead of `UTC` then there is no issue you'll see `Fri May 22 2020`.

Ok, now that we've fixed date issues, but we need to look into hours now :

Since you want docs **<= 22-May** then `Fri May 22 2020 00:00:00 GMT` doesn't work you need to have either `<= Fri May 22 2020 23:59:59 GMT` or `Sat May 23 2020 00:00:00 GMT`. In order to get that :

```
let date = new Date('2020-05-22')
date.setDate(date.getUTCDate()); // Setting utc date, Only useful if you're region is behind UTC
date = new Date(date.setHours(23,59,59,999)) // This overrides hours generated with 23:59:59 - which is what exactly needed here.

/** Now do your query */

{ date: { $lte: date }}
```

2. If your DB `date` field is of type `string` :

Then you don't need to convert string to date, instead you can send input date in string format :

```
let date = new Date('2020-05-22').toISOString() // 2020-05-22T00:00:00.000Z
/** Above would get you an ISO string no matter which region you're in, 
  * now since we need `2020-05-22T23:59:59.000Z` which is not easy on ISO string
  * We would just do +1 on date like `new Date('2020-05-23').toISOString()` - // 2020-05-23T00:00:00.000Z */

let date = new Date('2020-05-23').toISOString(); // like this
date = date.slice(0, -1) // removing `Z` from date string as your `date` field doesn't have this.
// Now your query is just `$lt`
{ date: { $lt: date }}
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2E9Tpl2-F9n)

Comment: Thanks, same idea with me, I have to set hours to 23:59:59 to covert fulltime of the day